# Unable to make use of all available space as reported by Gparted

Tags: virtualbox, gparted

I run Ubuntu 22.10 as a VM in VirtualBox (VB) hosted by Windows 10, and since I was running out of storage I decided to extend it.

- I increased the size of the virtual disk using The Virtual Media Manager in VB from about 30Gb to 46Gb
- Started Ubuntu in trial mode using the Ubuntu ISO installation file.
- I used GParted to extend the partition to all available space which according to GParted is now about 47Gb with 17Gb unused.
- I booted back into my original Ubuntu installation (not the trial one) and when I run df -h I see that the total storage is still about 30Gb, with the disk almost full, and getting warnings about "Low Disk Space".
- I tried various fixes suggested online (look at iNodes, use resize2fs, cleaning deleted files etc), but nothing helped to make available and visible in df the extra 17Gb reported by GParted as being unused.

Any suggestion on how to reclaim that extra 17Gb storage?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using LVM, and you'll need to follow instructions for extending the root file system.

Here's a tutorial showing you [How to extend root filesystem using LVM on Linux](https://computingforgeeks.com/extending-root-filesystem-using-lvm-linux/)